# Spotify player too big, unable to make it smaller. Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, spotify, add-on

I am trying to add a spotify music player to my website, a wordpress website. I tried with two different add-ons ,in one it was only available the widget player as a free option and the other one, give what I was looking for but I am not able to change the size of it.

The code is

```
[spotifyplaybutton play="spotify:album:6ttYxo44Qt6rC1z8ibKn9s" view=”coverart” size=”0″ sizetype=”compact” theme=”white”]
```

The only two sizetype available within the add-on is big or compact, in both cases I am getting the same size of the music player.

You can see how it looks like from the website, [griotblues.com/music](http://griotblues.com/music/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the approach mentioned [here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/spotify-play-button/)
You can specify the height and width of the player by setting the height and width properties of the iframe